# Cannot execute python popen.read in cmd

Tags: python, python-3.x, popen

I have this line in my python 3.8 code:
`os.popen(some_command).read()`

When running this program from IDLE it works fine but when running from cmd with `python program.py` it's stuck on this line.
I tried using `subprocess.check_output(some_command)` but it gives the same output

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please include your code as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: du you have just python3 installed or python2 to ?